# Get data as array from DB for each array item in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm coding a reactions plugin for WordPress and trying to create a chart with chart.js for admins of past 7 days reaction counts for each day. User reactions are recorded in database in following  columns: `postId`, `reactedTo`and `reactedDate`. example row will be `182`, `Haha` and `27 Jun 2019`.

I'm generating an array of past 7 days dates with the same format in JavaScript to create labels for the chart and also trying to send it on back-end via AJAX to get the count of each of this date record from database in an array format. So, for example, the database contains this data:

`postId   reactedTo   reactedDate`
`145      Like        22 Jun 2019`
`182      Haha        24 Jun 2019`
`182      Haha        27 Jun 2019`

I'm generating array of past 7 days using this code in JS:

```
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var lastWeek = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - i);
        lastWeek.push(d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear());
    }
    lastweek = lastWeek.reverse()

    console.log(lastweek);
```

> outputs ["21 Jun 2019","22 Jun 2019","23 Jun 2019","24 Jun 2019","25 Jun 2019","26 Jun 2019","27 Jun 2019"]

Then I'm sending it to the server via AJAX and generating chart on success.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'reactions_analytics',
            dates: JSON.stringify(lastWeek)
        },
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXhr) {
            var reactionsChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: lastWeek,
                    datasets: [{
                        data: response,
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The `response` from the server should be an array of numbers count for each date from the database. if date not found, then 0. So it should be `[0,1,0,1,0,0,1]`.

Here's my current PHP code to search in the database and generate an array of date counts in the same order, but it outputs empty array `[]` instead.

```
    public function reactionsAnalytics() {
        global $wpdb;
        $tableName = $wpdb->prefix.'reactions';
        $dates = json_encode($_POST['dates']);
        $reacts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT reactedDate, count(*) AS count FROM {$tableName} WHERE reactedDate IN ({$dates}) GROUP BY reactedDate", ARRAY_A);

        $result = array();
        foreach ($reacts as $react) {
            $result[] = $react['count'];
        }

        wp_die(json_encode($result));
    }
```

So I think I need help with my PHP. What is not correct in my logic? Can it do in a better way?

Basically I'm trying to send this to server: `["21 Jun 2019","22 Jun 2019","23 Jun 2019","24 Jun 2019","25 Jun 2019","26 Jun 2019","27 Jun 2019"]`

And get same array with count numbers for each date found in DB `[0,1,0,1,0,0,1]`

Comment: You made a mistake, $react does not exist outside your foreach. You probably just wanted to do wp_die($dates)

Comment: This won't fix the problem, because I'm sending those dates from JS to get the count of them. so wp_die(); should return array of numbers of those dates found in database.

Answer (score 0):

change the code as follows :

```
public function reactionsAnalytics() {
global $wpdb;
$tableName = $wpdb->prefix.'reactions';
$dates = str_replace("\\", "", $_POST['dates']);
$reacts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT reactedDate, count(*) AS count FROM {$tableName} WHERE reactedDate IN ({$dates}) GROUP BY reactedDate", ARRAY_A);

$result = array();
foreach ($reacts as $react) {
    $result[] = $react['count'];
}

wp_send_json_success($result);
```

}

Change the js code as follows:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: ajaxurl,
dataType : "json",
type: 'POST',
data: {
    action: 'reactions_analytics',
    dates: lastWeek.reverse()
},
success: function(response, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    if ( response.success === true ) {
        var reactionsChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: lastWeek,
                        datasets: [{
                            data: response.data,
                    }
                });
        } else {
            // error
            alert('error occured !');
        }
    }
}});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working and it's not returning an array of date counts in same order. My SQL query is the main issue perhaps here and not JS?

Comment: Yes, the main problem is the sql command, if you change the reactedDate column 
 data type to datetime  you can use the command order by for sorting ascending or descending

Comment: In that case, I won't be able to store and display dates in this format '27 Jun 2019'

Comment: why ?!! you can simply use date function ! or you can change the column value to timestamp and display date with any format

Comment: I'm using date function to get current date but if I change data type to datetime, it is storing just 0 zeroes, so my data type is varchar for date

Comment: you can save date with this format : Y-m-d H:i:s, first change column type to date time and then save date with that format

Comment: I know I can, but then I won't be able to display chart labels in '27 Jun 2019' format. I mean I will be able, but I'm using this chart labels as array items to send to server and get count for them in database.

Comment: I think there is no easier way to do this, you can send the same values to the server in the same way, then convert to timestamp and compare it very easily with the database.Only in this case, you can easily sort the values. Because of the poor design of the database, your code is complicated.

Comment: The problem is not even in sorting. I can't get counts for each of this dates from database. it outputs empty array.

Comment: OOPS, your problem is the value of the $dates variable, check the value of the variable see if there is a comma between any value. Use the print_r function to print the value of the variable and see the output in chrome developer tools

Comment: You were right. The problem was in $dates variable as it was returning array with [ ] and SQL Query needed ( ), so I used `str_replace` to replace [ ] with ( ) and query runs fine. The only problem now is that if date not found, it don't returns 0 in array, it just skips it. so it only return array of found dates count like [3,1] instead of [0,0,3,0,0,1,0].

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in $dates variable as it was returning array with [ ] and SQL Query needed ( ), so I used `str_replace` to replace [ ] with ( ) and query runs fine now.